# Aws cdk for simple workflow (SWF) domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-swf

I am using CDK for deployment of SWF application.

SWF workflow and activities are getting created when I start the worker.

I am searching about how to create swf domain using CDK instead of creating manually.
Any simple example to create domain with CDK will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

AWS's Simple Worlfow (SWF) does not have support in CloudFormation, and therefore does not have direct support in the CDK either.

While you could start writing Custom Resources to create SWF resources, I can't say it'd be terribly worth it. SWF is basically dead and not likely to see any changes going forward.

I would strongly consider looking at Step Functions and see if you can use that instead. There is CloudFormation support already and the CDK L2 constructs are good at building out workflows.